How to make Lazy-Loading work with dbcontext
My LazyLoadingProxies not work after I config my DbContext using LazyLoadingProxies here:
        services.AddDbContextPool<DbContext, ApplicationDbContext>((provider, builder) =>
        {
            var configuration = provider.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
            var options = provider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<SqlServerRetryOptions>>();

            builder
            .EnableDetailedErrors(true)
            .EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true)
            .UseLazyLoadingProxies(true) // => If UseLazyLoadingProxies, all of the navigation fields should be VIRTUAL
            .UseSqlServer(
                connectionString: configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionStrings"),
                sqlServerOptionsAction: optionsBuilder
                        => optionsBuilder.ExecutionStrategy(
                                dependencies => new SqlServerRetryingExecutionStrategy(
                                    dependencies: dependencies,
                                    maxRetryCount: options.Value.MaxRetryCount,
                                    maxRetryDelay: options.Value.MaxRetryDelay,
                                    errorNumbersToAdd: options.Value.ErrorNumbersToAdd))
                            .MigrationsAssembly(typeof(ApplicationDbContext).Assembly.GetName().Name));
        });

Here is RoleEntity:
public class Role : DomainEntity<int>
{

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}

I dont know why Users of Role is also include even though I dont use Include in the code
    public List<Role> FindAll()
        => context.Role.ToList();


Users are loaded automatically when you access property Users, for example in debugger view. It is what Lazy loading is supposed to do.

But in my FindAll function, Im not Access to Users

Sow, how do you know that Users are loaded?

You mean it only loaded when I debug right

I mean every time when you access Users property, EF Core initialise it. Including debugger. Enable EF Core logging to understand when SQL is sent. You also can remove virtual from property definition to disable Lazy loading.

“You keep using that word. I do not think it means what you think it means.”

Inigo Montoya, The Princess Bride.

A crash course in lazy vs. eager loading.
Lazy loading: When this is enabled and a navigation property is accessed, if it hasn't been loaded from the database, EF will immediately load it from the database.
Eager loading: Tells EF to immediately load the related data with the parent data.
So examples: with a fresh DbContext.
Eager loading:
public List<Role> FindAll()
{
    return context.Role
        .Include(r => r.Users)
        .ToList();
}

This will generate an SQL statement like:
SELECT r.*, u.* FROM Roles r 
    INNER JOIN UserRoles ur ON r.RoleId = ur.RoleId
    INNER JOIN Users u ON ur.UserId = u.UserId

Lazy loading:
public List<Role> FindAll()
{
    return context.Role
        .ToList();
}

This will initially generate an SQL statement like:
SELECT r.* FROM Roles r 

and only look to populate the role. However, EF assigns a proxy to the Role.Users collection, so as soon as any code, including the debugger (if you are checking to see if data is loaded or not), and importantly, things like serializers "touch" a role.Users navigation property you will see queries popping up like:
SELECT u.* FROM Users u
    INNER JOIN UserRoles ur ON u.UserId = ur.UserId
WHERE ur.RoleId = 1

This is where lazy loading can be a big problem because of interactions with things like serializers which will iterate over each Role and "touch" the Users collection on each. Imagine if you load 100 roles and serialize them.. You get:
SELECT u.* FROM Users u
    INNER JOIN UserRoles ur ON u.UserId = ur.UserId
WHERE ur.RoleId = 1
SELECT u.* FROM Users u
    INNER JOIN UserRoles ur ON u.UserId = ur.UserId
WHERE ur.RoleId = 2
SELECT u.* FROM Users u
    INNER JOIN UserRoles ur ON u.UserId = ur.UserId
WHERE ur.RoleId = 3
....
SELECT u.* FROM Users u
    INNER JOIN UserRoles ur ON u.UserId = ur.UserId
WHERE ur.RoleId = 100

Then imagine that the User entity has references to another entity, as the user gets serialized, that triggers SQL statements for each related entity for each user.
Where the Eager Loading scenario just loads all 100 roles and their associated users in one single call. This often is a better solution, but not always, especially when loading a lot of rows with a lot of eager loaded relations. This forms something called a Cartesian Product where the resulting footprint size of data becomes a multiple of all relationships. This can be mitigated to a degree via using AsSplitQuery(), but that has limitations when it comes to things like sorting & pagination.
For this reason lazy loading is disabled by default in EF Core. (It was enabled by default in EF .Net Framework) It should be avoided unless you have a good reason to enable it and are careful with its use.
There is a distinct caveat when it comes to how EF manages tracking references. If you happen to have references to related data already tracked by the DbContext then these references will be automatically populated when using Lazy Loading, or even when Lazy Loading is disabled and you don't use eager loading. For example if I have code that does this:
var users = context.Users.ToList();

then later call:
var roles = context.Roles.ToList();

Whether I have lazy loading enabled or not, when the DbContext returns me the Roles, it will automatically associate any/all Users that apply to each role. This can trip people up when they disable lazy loading because they will find related data being partially loaded, or loaded in some situations and not others where they forget to eager load reliably. This is one reason it is important to keep DbContext instances short-lived because the more entities a DbContext is tracking, the longer it takes to sift through potential relations when loading/returning more data.
The best solution when reading large amounts of data, such as search results, is to use ViewModels and projection rather than reading entire entities:
var roles = context.Role
    .Select(x => new RoleSummaryViewModel
    {
        RoleId = x.Id,
        Name = x.Name,
        UserCount = x.Users.Count()
    }).ToList();

The advantages of this is that you build queries that only return the data you actually need, and the DbContext does not end up tracking anything, it just populates these view models. (Just don't mix view models and entities, such as having a collection of User entities inside the view model) Then if you want to actually do something like Update a particular Role, fetch the Role entity by ID, make the changes, and save.
